# rename attribute value in foreach if multiple values exist same php magento

Tags: php, magento, foreach, data-migration

Hi i have a script which **fetch** all product data from **magento** , there is one **problem** occur which is there are **some** products whose **name** is **same** but **sku** is **different** , i want to **append** product name who has the **same** value **other** who has the **unique** value **should** not append...

```
<?php
@ob_start();
@session_start();
ini_set('display_errors', 1);
include '../../../../app/Mage.php';
umask(0);
Mage::app('default');

function empty_pk($data){
if($data!=''){return $data;}
else {return "&nbsp;";}
}
$collection = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->getCollection()->addAttributeToFilter('status', 1);
//arsort($collection);  

//echo'<pre>';
 //print_r($collection);die();
echo 'count===='.count($collection).'<br/>';
$i=0;
foreach ($collection as $product_all) { 
//echo $product_all->getId().'<br/>';
    if($i==10) break;  
 $id = $product_all->getId();        
 $neew = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->load($id);         
//echo'<pre>';

$product_id = $neew->getId();
$created_at = ' 2013-01-26 00:53:46';
$description = $neew->getdescription();
$short_description = $neew->getshort_description();
$sku = $neew->getsku();
$size_fit = $neew->getsize_fit();
$style_ideas = $neew->getstyle_ideas();
$name = $neew->getname();
```

how can i do this

Comment: don't get too **bold** in saying your problem.

Answer (score 0):

You can use temporary array for keeping names' counts and then filter by it:

```
function empty_pk($data){
if($data!=''){return $data;}
else {return "&nbsp;";}
}
$collection = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->getCollection()->addAttributeToFilter('status', 1);
//arsort($collection);  

$names = array();
foreach ($collection as $product_all) {
  $name = $product_all->getName();
  if (array_key_exists($name)) {
      $names[$name]++;
  } else {
      $names[$name] = 1;
  }
}
//echo'<pre>';
 //print_r($collection);die();
echo 'count===='.count($collection).'<br/>';
$i=0;
foreach ($collection as $product_all) { 
//echo $product_all->getId().'<br/>';
    if($i==10) break;  
 $id = $product_all->getId();        
 $neew = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->load($id);         
//echo'<pre>';

// Exit if unique.
if ($names[ $neew->getName() ] == 1) {
    break;
}

$product_id = $neew->getId();
$created_at = ' 2013-01-26 00:53:46';
```